# Sending request parameter using javascript to Servlet located in other domain in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a question about JSP-

I want to send request parameters  from `jsp` to `servlet` located on other domain server using javascript.

I know,there are some security policy for javascript.  Is it possible?

Specifically, what I try to do is that when i click some image tag at jsp on domain named www.helloWorld1.com , I want to send request parameter to other domain named www.helloWorld2.com/servlet as using javascript

Comment: You can use JSONP in jquery ajax call

Comment: Same origin policy doesn't apply for forms so you can just create a form on the fly using javascript and submit it (assuming you're not interested in response).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        crossDomain: true,
        type:"GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "http://www.helloWorld2.com/servlet?callback=?",
        data: {projectID:1},
        dataType: "jsonp",                
        jsonpCallback: 'fnsuccesscallback'
    });
```

Use jsonp which  is used for cross domain support.. and in the landing servlet use
`request.getParameter("projectID")` to  get the request parameter values

Comment: your code is very helpful for me . thanks to your help.

Comment: i am new to here , how to accept answer and I was able to solve my cross domain issue.  i hava question for you . in your code, crossDomain property is necessary ? and what is jsonpCallback property?

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking the check button which will be on left side of my answer.. and to answer your question 1. crossDomain is not mandatory 2. "fnsuccesscallback" will be the callback function which is a new function you will write, which will be called after you have recieved a response from server.